# Laravel cookie not set on home page but is set everywhere else

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5

We have this function in helpers.php that returns the lang

```
function locale() {
  if(Cookie::has('locale') && array_key_exists(Cookie::get('locale'), Config::get('languages'))) {
    $locale = Cookie::get('locale');
  } else {
    $locale = 'en';
  }
  return $locale;
}
```

On every single page, it works and returns the correct value. But, for some reason, on the index page only, it is always 'en'.

This is how we set it:

```
function setLocale(Request $request) {
  $locale = $request->input('locale');
  if(array_key_exists($locale, \Config::get('languages'))) {
    $cookie = cookie()->forever('locale', $locale);
    \App::setLocale($locale);
  }
  return redirect()->back()->withCookie($cookie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, it seems the error was that the home page route was in a group with the `web middleware`, but we were still setting it

```
Route::get('/', [
  'uses' => 'HomeController@index',
  'as' => 'root',
  'middleware' => 'web'
]);
```

removing the middleware from this part since it's already present in the route group solved the issue.